# Do we have Atom package for nodejs like Emmet to autocomplete?

Tags: node.js, atom-editor

Do we have **Atom package for nodejs** like **Emmet** to autocomplete?

Answer (score 0):

Since JavaScript is a **loosely coupled dynamic lanuage**, providing a foolproof autocomplete solution is not as easy as for statically typed languages like Java.

Good package candidates for **Atom** are:

- [ternjs](http://ternjs.net/) - this looks pretty good, but requires
  some configuration.
- [autocomplete-plus](https://github.com/atom/autocomplete-plus) - this is now bundled with Atom as the default
  autocomplete provider